# Geometric to Negative Binomial

Tags: statistics, convolution, negative-binomial

I have seen that X ~ G(p) and we have X - 1 ~ NB(1,p) (*)

I do not understand the meaning of (*)

I definitely know that geometric dist helps to find the number of trials till the first success and and the negative binomial dist helps to find the number of trials till the rth success 
In this case we have negative binomial dist with r = 1. Why it would not be the geometric dist itself but have to be one less than the geometric (as (*) indicated)

Any help is appreciated!!
Thanks for your help in advanced!!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I do not know what the (*) is attempting to address.

I would say that if we have $X\sim \text{NB}(1,p)$, then we also have that $X \sim \text{G}(p)$

Here is how the formula for the negative binomial turns into the formula for the geometric:

First we have that the general formula for the negative binomial, with $k$ successes in $n$ trials and we stop after the $k^{th}$ success, is: $$P(X=n) = \binom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k-1}(1-p)^{n-k}p$$
In the special case of $k=1$, see that 
$$P(X=n)=\binom{n-1}{1-1}p^{1-1}(1-p)^{n-1}p$$
$$=\binom{n-1}{0}p^0(1-p)^{n-1}p$$
$$=1*1*(1-p)^{n-1}p$$
$$=(1-p)^{n-1}p$$
Which is the formula for the geometric distribution with probability of success $p$.

There are a few different variations of the [Negative Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Definition) where the random variable $X$ means different things, so perhaps it was a different definition being used that the (*) was attempting to explain.

Comment: Thanks for that. It is really helpful. I have seen the (*) when i saw a youtube video when he is doing the sum of 2 indepedent geometric in order to obtain Z ~ NB(2,p). This is exactly what im looking for. However, during the process, it appears the (*) and im not sure if that makes sense. So i really wondering

Comment: I believe the YouTuber may have been defining the negative binomial as the number of **failures** until the first success, which would explain why it would have the minus one with it. However, in my answer, I defined it differently, which is why my answer is different, but neither one is wrong. You just have to make sure you know what you're defining the random variable to be.

Comment: Thanks for that. But X it is the independent geometric RV, X ~ NB(1,p) and X - 1 ~ NB(1,p) look quite different. So do you mean that if i define that is the number of failures until the first success then the (*) is correct and if i define that is the number of trials before the first success then what you have above is appropriate?  If these are true, could you please tell me why we take X - 1 ? Thank you :):)

Comment: What you just explained is correct. [This](https://youtu.be/JwTVxcp0GzA) is the YouTube video that I found when I looked it up. I'm not sure if it's the same one you referenced before, but this YouTuber defines the negative binomial as number of failures before the success, but yet defined the geometric random variable as the number of trials until the first success. If we have $X$ trials, then there would have to be $X-1$ failures. I hope this helps make it alot clearer :)

Comment: Haha. That is exact the video i have watched. Lesson learned. Thanks heaps heaps heaps :):)